# TeamCity dotCover code coverage stats on only new files

Tags: teamcity, dotcover

I'm running dotCover in TeamCity.  I can see the code coverage of the entire project I'm building/testing.  What I would like to see is: "for this change set, what is the code coverage?"  I.e. I'd like to see only the stats and only the files in the current change set.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. I've just created a feature request in YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-7109).